# Has_many with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello i have looked around and can't find an answer.

**I am trying to get all the approved products that are enabled for an outfit. Im thinking this can be done using a condition here:**

```
has_many :approved_outfit_products, -> { where(approved: true) },
         class_name: 'TaggedProduct', dependent: :destroy
```

Here is some extra info:

```
outfit.rb

has_many :products, through: :outfit_products
has_many :approved_outfit_products, -> { where(approved: true) },
         class_name: 'TaggedProduct', dependent: :destroy
has_many :approved_products, through: :approved_outfit_products, source: :product, dependent: :destroy
```

Outfit.find(1).approved_products will return me a list of products that have been approved. Out of this list of products i need the ones that have been **enabled**.

To understand what is going on better here is rails c

```
$ rails c
PLoading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
ro2.1.2 :001 > Product.new
 => #<Product id: nil, title: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, category_id: nil, size_description: nil, shipping_description: nil, price_in_cents: nil, enabled: true>
2.1.2 :002 > TaggedProduct.new
 => #<TaggedProduct id: nil, product_id: nil, outfit_id: nil, approved: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, receiver_id: nil, requester_id: nil>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what are you getting from this? `Outfit.find(1).approved_products.where('enabled = ?',true)`

Comment: see my answer, becuase enabled is not in this model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain `where` just add a `.where(enabled: true)`

Edit: ah hold on, you first need to join with products

so:

```
joins(:product).where(product: {enabled: true})
```

Comment: Sorry that wont work. The approved is on the TaggedProoducts table. The enabled is on the Product table.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you.